# cycles through everything while trying to select one thing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, 3d-view

is this normal behavior for Blender? at some point in my working in blender it starts to no longer let me just click on an object to select it when their are more then one within the work area.

Instead when I click on the object I want, it will not select it (right away), it cycles through everything until it gets to the one I want before it gets selected.

in object mode and pose mode. it is really annoying, so now I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is normal. This is the way Blender handles selectable objects that are coincident, or very close to each other. If it can't tell which one you want, it will cycle through each possible option until you stop on the one you want.

If you want to avoid this behavior, there are a few options.

- You may be able to move some objects to other layers.
- A little known tool is "Local View." Press numpad <kbd>/</kbd> in object mode to view *only* the selected object. Do what you want to it, and then press <kbd>/</kbd> again to see everything else again.
- Use <kbd>h</kbd> to hide selected objects
- Use <kbd>shift</kbd> to hide UNselected objects
- Use the Outliner to turn off selectability for certain objects

[image: Click the cursor arrows to toggle whether that object is selectable]

Comment: " If it can't tell which one you want, it will cycle through each possible option" my pointer/arrow is right on top of it and it still cycles. but thanks for the information on how to get around.

Comment: Yeah, that can be frustrating sometimes, but it really is the best option. Blender doesn't assume that you can always be as precise as you want, so it remains open to the possibility that the *closest* selection might *not* be the one you want ;-) There's been many times that I was glad Blender worked that way. Essentially, if you're having *that much trouble* selecting what you want, then it means your scene is complex enough to warrant the next level of organization.

Comment: just running through this riggy rigging youtube vid, seeing that dude having up what I do and he selects what I cannot. no biggy, it is just good to know that it is a normal behavior to cycle and it wasn't something I did with the settings that can be removed. I'll hopefully get use to it. :D